# iOS different layout per target and Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, storyboard, xib

If I have a white label application that maintains the same functionality but changes it's layouts according each brand, creating a new Target, what's the best way to manage those different layouts? We're considering the use of different xibs and inflating it according each target.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the level of customization between your different brands.

Creating a xib per target involves a lot of differences between the layouts, and it is the best solution for this case. You just create x times the xib/storyboard, and include the different version in each target.

Nevertheless, it might be easier to generalize your interface with specific customizable parts for future maintenance. Think about the fact when you will have to fix a UI bug, and have to correct **x** xibs/storyboards.

[image]